# r - How to Read Data from Multiple Workbooks having multiple Worksheets into R?

Tags: r

I am trying to read data from ***Multiple Workbooks*** which have ***Multiple Worksheets*** using r. There are 10 workbooks and each has data in two worksheets.

Following code works in pulling data from the first sheet. However I'd like to also pull the data on another sheet in the same workbook. I am not sure how to specify the sheet name in the following code.

```
library(purrr)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data_path <- "C:/Desktop/Test"

files <- dir(data_path, pattern = "*.xlsx")


weights_data <- data.frame(filename = files) %>%
               mutate(file_contents = map(filename,
                                                 ~ read_excel(file.path
                                                              (data_path,  .))))

View(unnest(weights_Data))
```

Comment: `read_excel(file.path, sheet=NULL)` is the default, have you tried changing `sheet=`? If in doubt, for each file `readxl::excel_sheets(file.path)` will return a vector of all of the sheets (their names, I believe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_excel` takes another argument that lets you specify a specific sheet:

```
sheet: Sheet to read. Either a string (the name of a sheet), or an
       integer (the position of the sheet). Ignored if the sheet is
       specified via 'range'. If neither argument specifies the
       sheet, defaults to the first sheet.
```

With that, we need to expand your frame of paths to include sheets, easily done with `readxl::excel_sheets` which for a single path returns a vector of sheet names.

Iteratively, for discussion/walk-through, though only the last block is required:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(readxl)

data_frame(
  path = list.files(path = "~/StackOverflow/Prah/", pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)
) %>%
  mutate(sheets = map(path, excel_sheets))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   path                                        sheets   
#   <chr>                                       <list>   
# 1 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt1.xlsx" <chr [2]>
# 2 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt2.xlsx" <chr [2]>
# 3 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt3.xlsx" <chr [2]>
```

This alone isn't immediately helpful, but we can `unnest` it:

```
data_frame(
  path = list.files(path = "~/StackOverflow/Prah/", pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)
) %>%
  mutate(sheets = map(path, excel_sheets)) %>%
  unnest(sheets)
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   path                                        sheets
#   <chr>                                       <chr> 
# 1 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt1.xlsx" Sheet1
# 2 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt1.xlsx" Sheet2
# 3 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt2.xlsx" Sheet1
# 4 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt2.xlsx" Sheet2
# 5 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt3.xlsx" Sheet1
# 6 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt3.xlsx" Sheet2
```

Now it should become clear that we now just need to iterate over each row using `map2` or similar, and we get a nested tidy frame with data:

```
data_frame(
  path = list.files(path = "~/StackOverflow/Prah/", pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)
) %>%
  mutate(sheets = map(path, excel_sheets)) %>%
  unnest(sheets) %>%
  mutate(data = map2(path, sheets, ~ read_excel(path = .x, sheet = .y)))
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   path                                        sheets data              
#   <chr>                                       <chr>  <list>            
# 1 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt1.xlsx" Sheet1 <tibble [32 x 11]>
# 2 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt1.xlsx" Sheet2 <tibble [32 x 11]>
# 3 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt2.xlsx" Sheet1 <tibble [32 x 11]>
# 4 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt2.xlsx" Sheet2 <tibble [32 x 11]>
# 5 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt3.xlsx" Sheet1 <tibble [32 x 11]>
# 6 "C:\\Users\\r2/StackOverflow/Prah/mt3.xlsx" Sheet2 <tibble [32 x 11]>
```

(I made a few excel workbooks, each had two sheets, each sheet had `mtcars` on it. Nothing fancy.)

Comment: Thanks this is perfect! However I do get this error mainly due to the data type:

Error in View : Column `X__6` can't be converted from character to numeric

Comment: That sounds like a problem with one of your worksheets. Once you figure out which worksheet(s) show this problem, you should look into questions on SO about incorrect column classes (there are several on such).

Comment: If that error is solely in `View`, then I'd say it's not really a problem with the process or your data. I think I used `View` a few times in my first year of R, I haven't looked at it since. I tend to use `str(data)`, and I think a lot of people like `dplyr::glimpse`.

Comment: I get the same error when I use glimpse. I am trying to pull data from only the sheets I really need instead of all sheets.

Comment: This is the error message I get "Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Column `X__6` can't be converted from character to numeric"

Comment: I understand. Read https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/cell-and-column-types.html about column classes and manually control one, some, or all columns.